# After rebooting netbeans my program doesn't work [Java]

Tags: java, netbeans, java-6

I have a big big issue with my code. 
After rebooting Netbeans my java project stop working. In a first moment the design didn't show up, but it was used to run, afterwards  this error: "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException" appeared.
I didn't touch the code after the reboot. I don't know what is going on!
this is the entire code, excepts the initialization of vars:

```
package TestPackage;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Alessandro
 */
public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form MainFrame */
    public MainFrame() {
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setResizable(false);
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {


        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jSplitPane1.setDividerLocation(440);

        jSplitPane2.setDividerLocation(180);
        jSplitPane2.setOrientation(javax.swing.JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);

        openModel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24));
        openModel.setText("Open existing model");
        openModel.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                openModelActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        createBtn.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24));
        createBtn.setText("Create new model");
        createBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                createBtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(77, 77, 77)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(openModel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(createBtn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 277, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(83, 83, 83))
        );

        jPanel2Layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {createBtn, openModel});

        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                .addComponent(openModel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 58, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(createBtn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 58, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(16, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jPanel2Layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.VERTICAL, new java.awt.Component[] {createBtn, openModel});

        jSplitPane2.setTopComponent(jPanel2);

        jList1.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
            String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList1);

        jSplitPane2.setRightComponent(jScrollPane1);

        jList2.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
            String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jList2);

        jTabbedPane1.addTab("Compartments", jScrollPane2);

        jList3.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
            String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        jScrollPane3.setViewportView(jList3);

        jTabbedPane1.addTab("Species", jScrollPane3);

        jList4.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
            String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        jScrollPane4.setViewportView(jList4);

        jTabbedPane1.addTab("Reactions", jScrollPane4);

        jSplitPane2.setRightComponent(jTabbedPane1);

        jSplitPane1.setLeftComponent(jSplitPane2);

        jPanel5.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(null, java.awt.Color.darkGray));

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 2, 12));
        jLabel2.setText("Here you can set the simulation algorithm to compute the simulation");

        buttonGroup1.add(jRadioButton1);
        jRadioButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12));
        jRadioButton1.setText("   Gillespie Direct Method (DM)");
        jRadioButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jRadioButton2.setModel(null);
        buttonGroup1.add(jRadioButton2);
        jRadioButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12));
        jRadioButton2.setText("   Rejection-based Stochastic Simulation Algorithm (RSSA)");

        jRadioButton3.setModel(null);
        buttonGroup1.add(jRadioButton3);
        jRadioButton3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12));
        jRadioButton3.setText("   Euler deterministic algorithm");

        jRadioButton4.setModel(null);
        buttonGroup1.add(jRadioButton4);
        jRadioButton4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12));
        jRadioButton4.setText("   Runge-Kutta-Fehlberg deterministic algorithm (RK45)");

        jRadioButton5.setModel(null);
        buttonGroup1.add(jRadioButton5);
        jRadioButton5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12));
        jRadioButton5.setText("   Hybrid Rejection-based Stochastic Simulation algorithm (HRRSA)");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel5Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel5);
        jPanel5.setLayout(jPanel5Layout);
        jPanel5Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel5Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jRadioButton1)
                    .addComponent(jRadioButton2)
                    .addComponent(jRadioButton3)
                    .addComponent(jRadioButton4)
                    .addComponent(jRadioButton5)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 667, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        jPanel5Layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {jRadioButton1, jRadioButton2, jRadioButton3, jRadioButton4, jRadioButton5});

        jPanel5Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel5Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel5Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(23, 23, 23)
                .addComponent(jRadioButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 23, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jRadioButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 23, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jRadioButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 23, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jRadioButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 23, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jRadioButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(51, 51, 51))
        );

        algorithmBtn.addTab("Algorithm", jPanel5);

        jPanel6.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(null, java.awt.Color.darkGray));

        jTextField2.setText("1");

        jTextField4.setText(" ");
        jTextField4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField5.setText(" ");

        jTextField6.setText("0.01");

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12));
        jLabel4.setText("Number of simulations to compute.");

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12));
        jLabel5.setText("Number of parallel threads used to simulate.");

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12));
        jLabel6.setText("Maxium time instant to simulate.");

        jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12));
        jLabel7.setText("time sampling used for storing time series.");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel6Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel6);
        jPanel6.setLayout(jPanel6Layout);
        jPanel6Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel6Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel6Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel6Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 613, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 613, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 613, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 613, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel6Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel6Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2)
                        .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 47, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 50, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 50, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel6Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel6Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel6Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel6Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel6Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel6Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel6Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addGroup(jPanel6Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                                .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(jPanel6Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 54, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(jPanel6Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                        .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 15, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGroup(jPanel6Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel6Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                        .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel6Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 28, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addGap(62, 62, 62))
        );

        jPanel6Layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.VERTICAL, new java.awt.Component[] {jTextField2, jTextField4, jTextField5, jTextField6});

        algorithmBtn.addTab("General Options", jPanel6);

        jPanel4.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(null, java.awt.Color.darkGray));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel4Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel4);
        jPanel4.setLayout(jPanel4Layout);
        jPanel4Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 687, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel4Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel4Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 221, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        algorithmBtn.addTab("Not compulsory Options", jPanel4);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24));
        jLabel1.setText("                                OPTIONS");
        jLabel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));

        jCheckBox1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 12));
        jCheckBox1.setText(" do Plot");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12));
        jLabel3.setText("Destination Folder:");

        jButton1.setText("Browse");

        jButton2.setText("RUN SIMULATION");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(algorithmBtn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 696, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 568, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jCheckBox1)
                                .addGap(286, 286, 286))
                            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 112, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jButton1)))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 234, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(103, 103, 103))))
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 47, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(algorithmBtn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 253, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                        .addComponent(jCheckBox1)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jButton1)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(97, 97, 97))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 91, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 56, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(48, 48, 48))))
        );

        jSplitPane1.setRightComponent(jPanel3);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jSplitPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 1146, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jSplitPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 520, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jMenu1.setText("File");

        jMenuItem1.setText("jMenuItem1");
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem1);

        jMenuItem2.setText("jMenuItem2");
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem2);

        jMenuItem3.setText("jMenuItem3");
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem3);

        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        jMenu2.setText("Edit");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

File f;
String filename;
JFileChooser chooser;

private void openModelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    chooser = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("TEXT FILES", "txt", "text");
    chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
    String modelSpec = readSpecification();
    spec = modelSpec;

}                                         
String spec;
private void createBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
// TODO add your handling code here:
    CreateModel model1 = new CreateModel();
    model1.setVisible(true);

}                                         

private void jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
// TODO add your handling code here:
}                                             

private void jTextField4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
// TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           


    public static void main(String args[]) {

         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public String readSpecification() {
        String spec1 = "";

        // trying to read from file the specification...
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while(line!=null) {
                spec += line + "\n";
                line = reader.readLine();
            }        
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return spec1;
    }

    public static String findVolume () {
        String line1;
        String res = "";
        String vol = "volume";
        String uom = "units of measurement";

    try {
        BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Alessandro\\Desktop\\Gemcitabine.txt"));

        while((line1 = reader1.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line1.toLowerCase().indexOf(vol) != -1) {
                if(line1.toLowerCase().indexOf(uom) == -1) { 
                    String[] str = line1.split("=");
                    res = str[1].split(" ")[0];
                }
            }
        }
        reader1.close();
         } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return res;
    }
```

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.isSelected(AbstractButton.java:308)
    at javax.swing.ButtonGroup.add(ButtonGroup.java:76)
    at TestPackage.MainFrame.initComponents(MainFrame.java:201)
    at TestPackage.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:34)
    at TestPackage.MainFrame$9.run(MainFrame.java:521)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:672)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:81)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:633)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:631)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:642)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Please help me, this code is so important to me.

Comment: Error message says: "  at TestPackage.MainFrame.initComponents(MainFrame.java:201)", but we can't see what line this is. Probably looking up this line will give you (or us) a clue.

Comment: I can't edited the question because I write more than 30000 chars D: The line in question is " buttonGroup1.add(jRadioButton2);

Comment: Remote debugging using telepathy is really difficult ... what tools are you using? Can you have a break point on that line, inspecting variables the moment when it happens? (And, "Elena" indicating Russian origin, you'r not trying to improve nuclear weapons to kill me?)